# Spring AOP : How to get Caller method arguments values into Spring Aspect class advice method

Tags: spring, spring-integration, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

As i am asking this question i didn't find any solution for my requirement.

Requirement :

Currently i am working on a project using Spring Boot with Rest and Spring Integration .

My Requirement was Log all the gateway service calls into audit table for success and failure both scenarios. Each Gateway contains the gateway specific information which has to be stored in audit table.I am using the spring AOP - @After Advice annotation to log audit information, But this annotation method is expecting audit values which are part of the gateway service CALLER method.

Example :

```
@Autowired
com.study.pattern.sample.app.gateway.EmployeGatewayservice employeGatewayservice;

public EmployeOutput getEmployeInformation(EmployeInput employeInput,AuditInput auditInput)
{
    employeGatewayservice.getEmployeInfomation(employeInput);
}
```

How can i get auditInput object in my advice .

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.study.pattern.sample.app.gateway..*(..))")
     protected void gateWayCalls()
     {

     }

      @After("gateWayCalls()")
      public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
         **// Here i need auditInput Object**
     }
```

I have limitations on calling the advice method on getEmployeInformation() 
because some of the service method contains the not gateways calls logic.

For my case i have to use Aspect on Gateways not on service methods.

I was looking for a solution how to get Caller method arguments in to my spring aop @After advice?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use `MethodInterceptor`:

```
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Bilan, i tried but it didn't work ,but i found other option created my own custom audit annotation with the values and i annotated the gateway methods with audit annotation , and these values i am retrieving in my Aspect .

Comment: Hi @Maddy, Could you please elaborate how did you do this.

Comment: sorry late response will share my git link